# Invalid argument. Culture ID 2155 (0x086B) is not a supported culture

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am currently getting the following error when I attempt to build my solution.

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(1353,9): error MSB3095: Invalid argument. Culture ID 2155 (0x086B) is not a supported culture.
>
> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(1353,9): error MSB3095: Parameter name: culture

I have already:

1. completely removed the solution from my disk and downloaded a clean, fresh copy from souce control.
2. restarted my machine and visual studio
3. re-installed .net framework (2.0, 3.0 SP2 & 3.5 SP1)

Anyone have any ideas what I can do to fix my build?

Development Machine Running on
OS: Windows Server 2003 R2; Standard Edition; SP1 [This is a VM]

[UPDATE] I was unable to solve this issue so fixed it in an alternative method. My development environment is setup as VM so I grabbed my backup and started fresh. This seemed to correct the issue and all was well until ....

Just today I am once again receiving the same error

Now this happened during the day and no service packs or updates have been applied. Everything was building perfect and then 5 minutes later when I ran a new build, error ...

[UPDATE 24-Sept-2009] So after wasting my entire day yesterday trying to fix this issue, I gave up for the night.  I came back into the office this morning to find that all of a sudden, for no reason, everything is working now.  Everything builds and I have no idea why.  This leads me to believe that again, one day, it will just stop working.  I still really want to know why this happened and how to fix it so that when it happens again, and it will, I will be able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Culture ID 2155 (0x086B) is Quechua (Ecuador) which may not be supported by your operating system.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb895996.aspx):

> Locales marked by an asterisk (*) are new to Windows XP Service Pack 2, and will not have any effect on Windows XP without SP2 or on Windows Server 2003.

```
Locale               LCIDHex  LCIDDec 
-------------------------------------
Quechua_Ecuador*     086b     2155
```

See also:

- Social.msdn: [Culture ID 2155 (0x086B) is not a supported culture](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/b466d947-871b-4dd2-9f0e-0d4d8d60686d)
- MSDN: [Locale IDs, Input Locales, and Language Collections for Windows XP and Windows Server 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb895996.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the information.  The only information that the Social msdn link you provided tells me the same thing I have already tried.  To re-install the .net framework.

I don't understand why my system wants to use a culture for Ecuador.  Any other thoughts?